# Trigger an event on Show/Hide of bootstrap3 typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

Trigger an event on Show / Hide of bootstrap typeahead, in twitter typeahead there is an option on when typeahead div is opened like typeahead:opened. Likewise do we have anything in bootstrap typeahead?

Comment: I just had a quick look at bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.2.2 and couldn't see any custom events being triggered, so it doesn't look like it does. That older version of typeahead does have support for calling a callback function through an "updater" option but not for the show or hide of the dropdown, you might as well use the later version of typeahead instead

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: Thanks @Daniel sure will use "twitter-bootstrap" instead the other one as a tag